# ScrollView in Easy Dialogue(Third Party) is cutting off child Layout in landscape mode

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview, landscape-portrait

**Now i have a possible hint what's going on Scrollview/ListView is considering the real Height and width of device to render layout. However in easy dialog box we can display it at (below/left/right/up) to any view. As Scrollview/ListView is considering whole device height so it isn't allowing scroll(Not needed when child layout is smaller that parent height).**

I have a scroll view layout which i am inflating in a view to pass to a third party dialogue box [EasyDialog](https://github.com/michaelye/EasyDialog). This is how i my Scroll View layout looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuAboutUs"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/about_us_ico" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/darkBlueColor"
            android:text="About Us"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuAboutApp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/about_app_ico" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="About App"
            android:textColor="@color/darkBlueColor"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuHistory"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/history_ico" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="History"
            android:textColor="@color/darkBlueColor"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    </View>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuNutritionChart"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/nutrition_ico" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Nutrition Chart"
            android:textColor="@color/darkBlueColor"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    </View>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuTvCommercial"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tvc_ico" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="TV Commercials"
            android:textColor="@color/darkBlueColor"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    </View>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuJingles"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/jingles_ico" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Jingles"
            android:textColor="@color/darkBlueColor"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

EasyDialog show complete layout view when I am in Portrait screen orientation mode. However when I change my phone orientation to landscape mode. Scroll view cut off child layout and doesn't scroll over complete child layout.This is how i am inflating my view for Easy Dialogue.

Here is how i am inflating easy dialogue

```
private void LeftMenu() {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_left_menu_main, null);

        menuAboutUs = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.menuAboutUs);
        menuAboutUs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AboutUsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("moduleName","Main");
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
            }
        });

        menuAboutApp = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.menuAboutApp);
        menuAboutApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AboutAppActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("moduleName","Main");
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
            }
        });

        menuHistory = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.menuHistory);
        menuHistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HistoryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("moduleName","Main");
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
            }
        });

        menuNutritionChart = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.menuNutritionChart);
        menuNutritionChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NutritionChartActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("moduleName","Main");
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
            }
        });

        menuTvCommercials = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.menuTvCommercial);
        menuTvCommercials.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TvCommercialActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("moduleName","Main");
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
            }
        });

        menuJingles = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.menuJingles);
        menuJingles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, JinglesActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("moduleName", "Main");
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
            }
        });



        EasyDialog easyDialog = new EasyDialog(MainActivity.this)
                .setLayout(view)
                .setBackgroundColor(MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteColor))
                // .setLocation(new location[])//point in screen
                .setLocationByAttachedView(ibLeftTitle)
                .setGravity(EasyDialog.GRAVITY_BOTTOM)
                .setAnimationTranslationShow(EasyDialog.DIRECTION_X, 1000, -600, 100, -50, 50, 0)
                .setAnimationAlphaShow(1000, 0.3f, 1.0f)
                .setAnimationTranslationDismiss(EasyDialog.DIRECTION_X, 500, -50, 800)
                .setAnimationAlphaDismiss(500, 1.0f, 0.0f)
                .setTouchOutsideDismiss(true)
                .setMatchParent(false)
                .setMarginLeftAndRight(24, 24)
                //.setOutsideColor(MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.overlay))
                .show();
    }
```

**My Content is less than actual physical size of device but location at which i display easy dialog plus my content exceeding the height of physical display size of screen in landscape mode.**